# Start new paragraph inside a table cell

Tags: tables, paragraphs

Look out for the \par below (on the row starting with "MSA" and notice it does not achieve the desired new paragraph.  How to achieve the desired effect? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}

\small{
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c c @{}}
\toprule
Characteristic & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Result}\\
 \cmidrule{2-3}
 & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate \\
 \midrule
Cell shape & Rod & Rod\\
Gram stain & $-$ & $-$\\
Oxidase & $+$ & $-$\\
Catalase & $+$ & $-$\\
Anaerobic & Growth (weak) & No growth\\
Motility & $+$ & $-$ or ? \\
Indole production & $+$ & $-$ or ? \\
Hugh \& Leifsons & ? & ? \\
MSA \par\medskip Growth \par Mannitol utilisation & Growth & No growth\\
%Growth in absence of salt & & \\ (Didn't get time to do this one.)
Colony pigmentation & White & White \\
Colony texture & Smooth, creamy & Waxy, pellet-like \\
Colony edges & Entire & Entire \\
Colony shape & Round & Round \\
Colony elevation & Flat & Buldge\\
Medium modifications & Cracked patterns & Clear halo, pits, liquification\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}

\end{figure*} 


\end{document}
```

**Edit:** A number of you have helpfully pointed out my motivation isn't clear.  "MSA" has two indented sub-entries underneath it.  If I was doing it in Word, it would look like this:

[image]

With this in mind you may wish to revise your answers. Thanks! :)

**Edit2:** Sorry, I removed \medskip immediately following /par.  It is no longer needed.  The aim is to be able to start new paragraphs inside a table cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tabular` environment redefines `\par` to be `\@empty`:

```
\let\par\@empty
```

To obtain the "original" meaning of `\par` you could use a `\multicolumn` with a `p{}`-type column. However, in this case you don't really need to introduce new paragraphs in the cell; you can do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
  \small
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l c c @{}}
    \toprule
    Characteristic & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Result}\\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & Seaweed isolate & Coral isolate \\
    \midrule
    Cell shape & Rod & Rod\\
    Gram stain & $-$ & $-$\\
    Oxidase & $+$ & $-$\\
    Catalase & $+$ & $-$\\
    Anaerobic & Growth (weak) & No growth\\
    Motility & $+$ & $-$ or ? \\
    Indole production & $+$ & $-$ or ? \\
    Hugh \& Leifsons & ? & ? \\
    MSA \\
    \hspace*{0.5cm}Growth & $+$ & $-$ \\
    \hspace*{0.5cm}Mannitol utilisation & $+$ & ? \\
    %Growth in absence of salt & & \\ (Didn't get time to do this one.)
    Colony pigmentation & White & White \\
    Colony texture & Smooth, creamy & Waxy, pellet-like \\
    Colony edges & Entire & Entire \\
    Colony shape & Round & Round \\
    Colony elevation & Flat & Buldge\\
    Medium modifications & Cracked patterns & Clear halo, pits, liquification\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*} 

\end{document}
```

Note that I used `\centering` instead of the `center` environment to avoid extra vertical space and that `\small` doesn't require the use of braces (it's a switch with no arguments). I also used `table*` instead of `figure*`.

Comment: Can you please explain what multicolumn is doing in your solution?  I'm trying to understand why it's needed...   Thanks.

(PS. \par\medskip is needed in table cells to conserve horizontal space because I often insert tables in a two-column document, where the table is confined to the width of half the page.  Secondly, not here, but it's often needed because I have a lot of content in some table cells which when broken down into logical paragraphs helps with readability.)

Comment: @ptrcao: the second argument of `\multicolumn` overrides the original format declaration for the column, so using (as in my code) `\multicolumn{1}{p{2.8cm}}{...}` means that now the column behaves as a `\parbox` and now you can use `\par`. However, taking into account the new information in your EDIT, I'll propose another simpler alternative in my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without imposing a fixed width 2.8cm?  I want my table columns to be dynamic and adaptable, not fixed.  Thanks. :)

Comment: @ptrcao: see the update to my answer.

Comment: One last thing; the reason why I used figure was because of the advice given at http://andrewjpage.com/index.php?/archives/48-Figure-spanning-2-columns-in-Latex.html.  Suppose I still wanted the table to span 2 columns without having to end multicols environment and then restart after the table.  Any idea how this might be done?