# Table paragraph spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, xetex

In the preamble of my document, I'm using `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` to make a new line between each paragraph. But when I try to write paragraphs inside a table:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|p{0.85\textwidth}}
aaa & Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2
\end{tabular}
```

the paragraph skip is ignored, and it doesn't even give me an indentation:

[image]

My tables have long texts in them so the paragraph skip is really desirable for reading. Also, this breaks the newline `\\` for me.

As far as I understand, [\tabular redefines \par to be empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18730/start-new-paragraph-inside-a-table-cell/18733#18733) but the solution proposed seemed a bit too advanced for my needs. I tried with `\endgraf` after each paragraph without any result.

I'm using xelatex. Any help?

Edit: The above code is my minimum test case. I would like to use the paragraphs in the following environment:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{swedish}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newenvironment{exercise}[1]
{
    \begin{tabular}{m{0.05\textwidth}|P{0.85\textwidth}}
    \rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Övning}} & \textbf{#1}
}
{\end{tabular}
\bigskip
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `array` you could define a new column type which applies the paragraph skip to each cell in the column:

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{%
  \parskip=0.5\baselineskip%
  \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{30pt plus 1fil}}p{#1}}
...
\begin{tabular}{l|P{0.85\textwidth}}
...
\end{tabular}
```

The values are taken from the `parskip` package which you are using.

Comment: Very well then. I will open a new question and accept the answer for this one.